# Javascript ajax replace url

Tags: javascript, ajax, replace

I want to get div(content_id) of any web site to my page(#mydiv). I tried to below codes.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://example.com',
    type:'GET',
    success: function(data){
       $('#mydiv').html($(data).find('#content_id').html());
    }
});
```

I have many error like this;

```
http://127.0.0.1/web/Content/icons/chart5.png (404 Not Found)
http://127.0.0.1/web/Content/icons/chart12.png (404 Not Found)
....
```

I tried `replace('/web/', 'http://example.com/web/')`

But it does not work. Can any body help me?
Thanks...

Comment: Before you start looking for the HTML content, have you checked the result of: `$('#mydiv').html($(data)` ? Assuming that you don’t really mean `example.com`, and assume that there really is a `div#mydiv`, you’re expecting the loaded data to appear inside the div. Is that happening?

Comment: Use `$('#mydiv .replace').load('http://example.com #content_id > *')` instead of your Ajax. If no element found inside URL response, than element will not be replaced

Comment: I can get div content from example.com. But, I cannot see png, jpg etc. Because, html use 127.0.0.1/web/..., I want to example.com/web/...